# Not sure if Wine was actually uninstalled

Tags: 18.04, wine, uninstall, software-uninstall

I'm new to Ubuntu and tried to install wine earlier. I decided I didn't want to continue with the install though, so I tried to uninstall it using

```
sudo apt-get remove wine --purge
```

but whenever I open the terminal and type

```
wine
```

, my system says

```
Usage: wine PROGRAM [ARGUMENTS...]   Run the specified program
       wine --help                   Display this help and exit
       wine --version                Output version information and exit
```

which makes me think that wine is still installed somewhere since the system recognizes the wine command. Is wine completely uninstalled off of my system? If not, how would I do that? I installed using the directions on this page for Ubuntu 18.04: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the `apt-get remove ...` command did in fact remove `wine`? When I just tried it I got this message on 18.04.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove wine --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Virtual packages like 'wine' can't be removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 192 not upgraded.
```

As the message states, `wine` is a virtual package so you cannot remove it. You could remove it like this though:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge wine*
...
se 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wine-stable* wine1.6* wine64*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 192 not upgraded.
After this operation, 869 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
...
```

In this scenario you're telling `apt-get` to remove all packages that match your pattern, `wine*` which will get rid of all packages that match the pattern.

Comment: What is a virtual package? Does that indicate that all files downloaded and installed to my system from when I downloaded and installed Wine are now gone? Also, when I ran the commands in the second part of your message, it returned this: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winehq.key
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'winehq.key'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'winehq.key'`

Comment: Basically, I suppose I am just asking if the messages that I have provided from the terminal indicate that all Wine files that did not already come pre-installed with Ubuntu 18.04 (if any) are gone.

Comment: @jflinux - if you have files in the directory w/ those names the `wine*` glob will match them. If that's the case change it to `wine\*`.

Comment: @jflinux - a virtual package is covered in the FAQ - https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-virtual.

Comment: You were right, changing it to ```$ sudo apt-get purge wine\*``` fixed the issue, thank you so much!!